# Transparent ListView not working

Tags: android

In main activity i have one lisview ..i want to make the listview transparent such that image on main activity is shown as background of listview.I have tried to make the backgroung of listview android:background="@color/transparent" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
but no change

Comment: Do you use custom view for rows ?

Comment: i have used custom adapter

Comment: post `Adapter` for `ListView` code.

Comment: Can you post your code for both adapter and xml code of listView ?

Comment: Try setting the background of the parent viewgroup where the listview is also transparent.

Comment: public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
 super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 
 this.context=context;
 this.itemname=itemname;
 this.imgid=imgid;
 }

Comment: <RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
    android:background="@drawable/ajad" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"android:background="@drawable/ajad" >
    </ListView></RelativeLayout>

Comment: @jaspalsaini Post `getView()` method of your adapter.

Comment: edit question, don't post code in comment.

Comment: public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) { LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater(); View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);TextView txtTitle =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item); ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
 TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]); imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);extratxt.setText("Descripton "+itemname[position]); return rowView;
 };

Answer (score 0):

Using background attribute on root layout in XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#FFFF00"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and a simple ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.systems));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

gave me a transparent listView where i can see background color of my choice. Hope it helps.

Note: Tested on 4.3